# Cannot remove local DNS servers and domain

Tags: 18.04, dns, netplan

Initial disclaimer: I rarely build Linux servers, so I am not always up to date on my Linux skills.

I am setting up a DNS server for test and I need it to not see our local DNS or domain. I have set up static IPs with nameservers pointing to Google (and thanks 18.04 for making me learn netplan). Everytime I query my nameservers it show the 2 google servers and my two domain servers declared for DHCP. DHCP is disabled, yet I cannot get them to go away. When I check resolv.conf I can manually remove my domain, but as soon as I reapply netplan, it comes back. I can't have any crossover , as this needs to be an island. I don't want to install BIND until I can resolve this. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `netplan`, it automatically configures your network interfaces including the resolv.conf.

You can update your resolv.conf permanently by updating `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` and restarting `resolvconf` service.

You can check the [link](https://datawookie.netlify.com/blog/2018/10/dns-on-ubuntu-18.04/) for more details.

Comment: That did the trick I was looking for. Damn netplan changes. Why fix something that wasn't broken.

Comment: resolvconf is no longer installed by default on 18.04 and later and will only be present if you upgraded from a previous release.